# 'Any heavyweight can defeat any lightweight.' : How do you bracket the Nested Conditional?

Tags: logic

> <sub>Source: p 498, *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014) by Patrick Hurley</sub>
>
> Any heavyweight can defeat any lightweight.
> [1.] (x) [ Hx ⊃ **(y)** **(** Ly ⊃ Dxy **)** ]

Even after reading [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/31118/8572), Nested Conditionals still confuse me.
I bolded the only 2 changes. Why is it wrong to translate 1 as 3 below?
I pursue only intuition; please do not answer with formal proofs or Truth Tables.

> 3. (x)  [ **(y)** **(** Hx ⊃ Ly **)** ⊃ Dxy ]

Comment: Why would you translate it in that way?

Comment: @Keelan My problem is that I am confused (and do not know) which way is correct, for Nested Conditionals.

Comment: Now **it is** wrong; as already discussed at lenght : **A ⊃ (B ⊃ C)** and **(A ⊃ B) ⊃ C** are not equivalent: see truth table.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks. Yes, I remember, but as I wrote above, I still am entirely confused how to select which.

Comment: A good rule of thumb would be: if the sentence isn't grammatically awkward, use A ⊃ (B ⊃ C). Here, the sentence ("if x is heavyweight then if y is lightweight then x can defeat y") isn't too awkward. The other way around would be "if it is true that if x is heavyweight then y is lightweight, *then* x can defeat y" which is much more awkward.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a step-by-step approach.

We have already learned that : "Every human is mortal" is formalized as :

> **(x) ( Hx ⊃ Mx )**.

Now conisder [1.] : "Any heavyweight can defeat any lightweight" and firstly "approximate" it as : "Any heavyweight is a defeater".

This statement has the same logical form of the previous example, i.e.:

> **(x) ( Hx ⊃ Defx )**.

Now consider : "**x** is a defeater of any lightweight". We can rewrite it as "Any lightweight is a defeated by **x**",i.e.:

> **(y) ( Ly ⊃ Dxy )**.

Now you have only to replace "**x** is a defeater" [i.e. **Defx**] with "**x** is a defeater of any lightweight" [i.e. **(y) ( Ly ⊃ Dxy )**] to get :

> **(x) ( Hx ⊃ (y) ( Ly ⊃ Dxy ) )**.

Answer (score 0):

What makes your version wrong has nothing to do with the quantifiers.  As Mauro pointed out, the general form (A ⊃ B) ⊃ C is NOT equivalent to A ⊃ (B ⊃ C).  What you want is (A & B) ⊃ C.

With that in mind, you could write this

(x) [ (y) ( Hx & Ly ) ⊃ Dxy ]